# How to make element appear on hover of another

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

How do I make .instagramhandle appear on hover of .instagrambutton?

code:

```
html ->https://pastebin.com/iDFjMh1a
css ->https://pastebin.com/hKix29UB
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
 
body {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
}
 
div.topcontainer {
    background-image: url("m.p2.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 10px -5px black;
 
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
 
div.bottomcontainer {
    margin-top: 500px;
    background-color: #AA3939;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 
}
 
div.topbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: inherit;
 
}
 
.title {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
 
}
 
.instagrambutton {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
 
.instagrambutton:hover + .instagramhandle{
    display: block;
 
}
 
.instagramhandle {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    top: 5px;
    right: 100px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="masonStyleDef.css">
        <title>majic.photography</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="topcontainer">
            <div class="topbar">
                <h1 class="title">majic<br>Photography</h1>
                <p class="instagramhandle">majic.photography</p>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/majic.photography/" target="_blank"><img src="instagram-logo-white.png" alt="majic.photography" class = "instagrambutton"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="bottomcontainer">
                <h1 class="title">ohhhh boio</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you paste the code here...

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in CSS without changing the HTML markup. But this can be done using JavaScript,

```
var instaButton = document.getElementsByClassName('instagrambutton')[0];
var instaHandle = document.getElementsByClassName('instagramhandle')[0];

instaButton.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {
  instaHandle.style.display = 'block';
});

instaButton.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {
  instaHandle.style.display = 'none';
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
var instaButton = document.getElementsByClassName('instagrambutton')[0];
var instaHandle = document.getElementsByClassName('instagramhandle')[0];

instaButton.addEventListener("mouseenter", function( event ) {
  instaHandle.style.display = 'block';
});

instaButton.addEventListener("mouseleave", function( event ) {
  instaHandle.style.display = 'none';
})
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');
 
body {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
}
 
div.topcontainer {
    background-image: url("m.p2.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 10px -5px black;
 
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
 
div.bottomcontainer {
    margin-top: 500px;
    background-color: #AA3939;
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 
}
 
div.topbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: inherit;
 
}
 
.title {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;
 
}
 
.instagrambutton {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
 
.instagrambutton:hover + .instagramhandle{
    display: block;
 
}
 
.instagramhandle {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    top: 5px;
    right: 100px;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="masonStyleDef.css">
<div class="topcontainer">
            <div class="topbar">
                <h1 class="title">majic<br>Photography</h1>
                <p class="instagramhandle">majic.photography</p>
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/majic.photography/" target="_blank"><img src="instagram-logo-white.png" alt="majic.photography" class = "instagrambutton"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="bottomcontainer">
                <h1 class="title">ohhhh boio</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find the code here. Only with CSS.

[https://jsfiddle.net/Bhavani7/s1yduoLe/][1]

```
<div class="topcontainer">
        <div clasbs="topbar">
            <h1 class="title">majic<br>Photography</h1> 

        <div class="instagrambutton"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/majic.photography/" target="_blank"><img src="instagram-logo-white.png" alt="majic.photography"/></a><div class="instagramhandle"><p>majic.photography</p></div></div>
        <div class="bottomcontainer">
            <h1 class="title">ohhhh boio</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto');

body {
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
}

div.topcontainer {  
    background-image: url("m.p2.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position:absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 6px 10px -5px black;

    background-attachment: fixed;
}

div.bottomcontainer {
    margin-top: 500px;
    background-color: #AA3939;
    position:absolute; 
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;

}

div.topbar {
    position: fixed;
    width: inherit;

}

.title {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-left: 25px;

}

.instagrambutton {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px;
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10px;
    top: 25px;
    right: 25px;
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.instagrambutton:hover .instagramhandle{
    display: block;
}

.instagramhandle {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 20px;
    top: 5px;
    right: 100px;
    display: none;
}
```